# Export a Minecraft Realms world to a locally hosted bedrock server

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’ve been paying for a Minecraft realm for a while now but now have a static ip and a half decent internet connection so have recently been self hosting a bedrock server myself.

Is it possible to export the realm world and use it on my bedrock server and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To download a world from one of your Realm’s slots, follow these
> instructions:
>
> - Enter the Realm’s slots screen.
> - Select the Realm slot with the world you want to download. Choose Edit World.
> - Select Download World if you want to download the most recent version of that world.
> - When the download is complete, choose Let's Go!
> - Your downloaded Realm world will now appear in your local worlds list. You can play on this world offline and continue to make progress.

Source: https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/realms/change-realm-world

You could then find the world in your `C:\Users\(your pc username)\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MinecraftUWP_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\games\com.mojang\` folder.